Blackbody in the gaseous state
Let's say that the blackbody is made up of some weird, not yet discovered, atoms. The radiation described by the Planck's law is the one emitted from such atoms when they're packed together, forming what we call a SOLID material, and brought into thermal equilibrium. Now, let's imagine we heat that solid material, we heat it enough to turn it into vapour. My question now is, would the emission of this vapour be the expected discrete lines, losing therefore the characteristics of the blackbody radiation, as it is expected? The answer seems a big yes, but I don't know, am I right?

It depends how much gas you have and what the opacity as a function of frequency looks like.
If the gas is thick enough (in the optical sense of being opaque) at any frequency, then it will emit at those frequencies too; via the microscopic inverse of whatever mechanism is providing the absorption. The spectrum would be continuous.
On the other hand, if is thin at frequencies outside of the frequencies corresponding to atomic transitions but thick (or at least thicker) at those frequencies, then an emission line spectrum is expected.
